# reshaping dataframe with one names_to() and two values_to()

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am struggling with reshaping dataframes on R. My dataframe `pippo` looks
as follows:

> 

```
Brand  share2012  --- share2021 volume2012 --- volume2021
 1        0.2          0.1         15             18
 2        0.5          0.2        bla             urc
 3        0.3          0.7        blob            sdo
```

And so on. I would like to have a unique temporal dimension and have both the shares and the volume side by side,

```
Brand  Year  Share1 Volume 
 1     2012         
 1     2013           
 1     2014
```

How do I do this with `pivot_long()`?

I am stuck, I have no idea, I tried to reshape long twice, but it does not work:

```
longhino_df_cpsNBO <- pivot_longer(pippo,
                               cols = `share2012`:`share2021`,
                               names_to = "Year",
                               values_to = "CNBO_pct")

long_df_cpsNBO <- pivot_longer(longhino_df_cpsNBO,
                               cols = starts_with("volume"), 
                               names_to = "Year_Unit",
                               values_to = "Volumes_CNBO")
```

Comment: Can you add reproducibel data? Should it look like this? `pippo <- data.frame(Brand=c(1,2,3),
                    share2012=c(0.2,0.5,0.3),
                    share2021=c(0.1,0.2,0.7),
                    volme2012=c(15,'bla','blob'),
                    volume2021=c(18,'urc','sdo'))`

Comment: `pivot-_longer(df, -Brand, names_to =c('.value','Year'), names_pattern='([a-z]+)(\\d+)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to rename the columns to get a good separator:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>% 
  rename_with(., ~gsub("e", "e_", .)) %>% 
  # rename_with(., ~str_replace(., "e", "e_")) %>% #needs library(stringr)
  pivot_longer(-Brand, 
               names_to =c('.value','Year'),
               names_sep = "_")
```

```
  Brand Year  share volume
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 2012    0.2 15    
2     1 2021    0.1 18    
3     2 2012    0.5 bla   
4     2 2021    0.2 urc   
5     3 2012    0.3 blob  
6     3 2021    0.7 sdo
```

Comment: This seems more human! I still do not understand the connection between `.value` and `name_sep = _`

Comment: The `.value` is a special placeholder that represents the value column created by `pivot_longer()`. All values in the pivoted column will be placed in a new column with the name specified by `.value`.  `names_to` argument splits the original column names into two columns: `Year` and `.value`. `names_sep` specifies the separator `_`to use between the column name and the value column name. The part before the separator `_` becomes the `Year` column, and the part after the separator becomes the `.value` (here: `share` and `volume` column.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in a single `pivot_longer` by specifying the `names_to` as a vector of `.value` and the 'Year' which matches the captured patterns in `names_pattern` (`(.*)` - zero or more characters, `(\\d{4})`- four digits at the end (`$`) of the string)

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(pippo,  cols = -Brand,
                               names_to = c(".value", "Year"),
                               names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d{4})$")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Brand Year  share volume
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 2012    0.2 15    
2     1 2021    0.1 18    
3     2 2012    0.5 bla   
4     2 2021    0.2 urc   
5     3 2012    0.3 blob  
6     3 2021    0.7 sdo
```

#### data

```
pippo <- structure(list(Brand = 1:3, share2012 = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.3), 
    share2021 = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.7), volume2012 = c("15", "bla", "blob"), volume2021 = c("18", 
"urc", "sdo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: What does the dot stand for in `.value`?

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli According to `?pivot_longer` - `".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding values_to entirely.` which is also mentioned in the `vignettes` `Note the special name .value: this tells pivot_longer() that that part of the column name specifies the “value” being measured (which will become a variable in the output).`

Comment: I do not understand what is the argument of `names_pattern`, I do not understand what is the argument of `extract`. More in general, I can't believe that reshaping a freaking panel on R becomes a 1 day odissey.

Comment: I also receive an error. I am sorry, I do not understand what you are doing.

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli Where is `extract` being used in the code?  Regarding the error, not clear.  I showed a reproducible example with `dput` in my post.  It is not receiving any error for me

Comment: @MatteoBulgarelli  If you find the tidyverse difficult to understand, may be use `data.table` melt or if that is also difficult, you could use base R reshape.  My solution is an approved tidyverse method as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to `pivot_longer()` first, then `pivot_wider()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Brand, ~share2012, ~share2021, ~volume2012, ~volume2021,
  1, 0.2, 0.1, 15, 18,
  2, 0.5, 0.2, 16, 19,
  3, 0.3, 0.7, 14, 25
)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = !Brand,
    names_pattern = "(share|volume)(\\d{4})",
    names_to = c("type", "year")
  ) |> pivot_wider(
    names_from = type,
    values_from = value
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Brand year  share volume
#>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 2012    0.2     15
#> 2     1 2021    0.1     18
#> 3     2 2012    0.5     16
#> 4     2 2021    0.2     19
#> 5     3 2012    0.3     14
#> 6     3 2021    0.7     25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>